# NodeJs routing Middleware works even without path

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

This is the code im using

in webserver.js

```
var objApiServer = require('./node_scripts/ApiServer');
app.use('/APICalls/', objApiServer);
```

and in ApiServer.js

```
module.exports = function (router, request) {

//FUNCTION 
router.get('/GetDbData', function (req, res) {
/* SAMPLE CODE GOES HERE */
});

}
```

The on url path

> //mysite.domain/APICalls/GetDbData

its working fine

but it works on

> //mysite.domain/GetDbData (which i dont want)

did i missed something . what if i want to have a another function

for //mysite.domain/GetDbData

I put the another function in webserver.js with

```
app.get('/GetDbData' .......
```

but its not getting any calls

Answer (score 1):

Here's the demo code. Please try to implement this way:

In webserver.js --

```
var express = require('express');
var objApiServer  = require('./router/ApiServer');

var app = express();

app.use('/APICalls/', objApiServer);

app.listen(3000);
```

In ApiServer.js --

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/GetDbData', function(req, res, next) {
    /* SAMPLE CODE GOES HERE */
    res.send("GetDbData route called");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Below is the screenshot of the output for above code snippet :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: let me try and i think its similar to what i implemented. anyway thanks a lot for the screenshots sharing because its helps others to understand my question ... :-)

Comment: i had some more  " app.use('/', objAnother);  " in the webserver.js file and when commented them all it works ...

Comment: @DrVishnu As you said, after commenting out other `app.use(.....)` your code works. Can you please share some more code from your `webserver.js`. So that we can have better idea of what is getting wrong or what needs to be changes to work your full code.

Comment: thanks Rohit i was debugging the issue .. the problem is like that if we have any router with "app.use('/', objAnother)"; we can call any function insider the routers without full path ... i will post the reply as answer to quote the code ..thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the common router object. You may create a new router object in each routes file such as ApiServer.js, ApiServer1.js etc.

Below is th code snippet for the same:

In webserver.js

```
var objApiServer = require('./node_scripts/ApiServer');
var objApiServer1 = require('./node_scripts/ApiServer1');
app.use('/APICalls', objApiServer(router, request));
app.use('/GetDbData', objApiServer1(router, request));
```

In ApiServer.js

```
module.exports = function (router, request) {
  //FUNCTION 
  return new express.Router()
  .get('/GetDbData', function (req, res) {
     /* SAMPLE CODE GOES HERE */
  })
  .post('/PostDbData', function (req, res) {
     /* SAMPLE CODE GOES HERE */
  });
}
```

In ApiServer1.js

```
module.exports = function (router, request) {
  //FUNCTION 
  return new express.Router()
  .put('/UpdateDbData', function (req, res) {
     /* SAMPLE CODE GOES HERE */
  });
}
```

Comment: its the same code i posted.... did u checked my question .... ? i dont want router function to work when the path doesnt have "/APICalls/"

Comment: hey, i have made changes to the answer. Please check @DrVishnu

Comment: thanks for the change but i dnt understand why i need to have extra router ? u can check the below answers screenshot . thats what i need .....

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue and im posting my answer here . i had multiple routes and among them one was like

```
app.use('/APICalls/', objApiServer);
app.use('/RouterA', objRouterA);
app.use('/', objRouterB);
```

The last route was the issue. Its enables the calls to any router function without full Path. So if i call

> //mysite.domain/APICalls/func1APICalls

and

> //mysite.domain/func1APICalls

it will be routed to same function inside "objApiServer"

changing last line to

```
app.use('/B/', objClassA);
```

solved the issue